# How to include path information in data extracted from text files with FileSource

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We’ve got time-stamped directories containing text files, stored in HDFS.

We can regularly get new files added, so we’re using a `FileSource` (Flink 1.14.4, and a streaming job) with a monitoring duration, so that it continuously picks up any new files.

The challenge is that we need to include the parent directory’s timestamp in the output, for doing time-window joins of this enrichment data with another stream.

Previously I could extend the input format to extract path information, and emit a `Tuple2<LongWritable, Text>` (see my [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68764550/231762) to a question about doing that).

But with the new FileSource architecture, I’m really not sure if it’s possible, or if so, the right way to go about doing it.

I’ve wandered through the source code (FileSource, AbstractFileSource, SourceReader, FileSourceReader, FileSourceSplit, ad nauseam) but haven’t seen any happy path to making that all work.

There might be a way using some really ugly hacks to TextLineFormat, where it would reverse engineer the FSDataInputStream to try to find information about the original file, but feels very fragile.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Edit the following "StreamFormatAdapter.java" in package "org.apache.flink.connector.file.src.impl":

```
public final class StreamFormatAdapter<T> implements BulkFormat<T, FileSourceSplit> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StreamFormatAdapter.class);

        private final StreamFormat<T> streamFormat;

        public static final String DEFAULT_CHARSET_NAME = "UTF-8";

        public static final String FILE_NAME_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        ...
```

Last two lines are for charset and separator. Normally this should be included in "reader.StreamFormat" but it seems there is no way of using it there, see last section of my post.

The following code inserts the file path at the beginning of the InputStream by using SequenceInputStream and Flink's InputStreamFSInputWrapper to cast to FSDataInputStream and generating a TrackingFsDataInputStream:

```
    private static TrackingFsDataInputStream openStream(
        final Path file, final Configuration config, final long seekPosition)
        throws IOException {

            ...
            final InflaterInputStreamFactory<?> deCompressor =
                    StandardDeCompressors.getDecompressorForFileName(file.getPath());

            final String fileName = file.toString() + FILE_NAME_SEPARATOR;
            final InputStream fileNameStream =
                    org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toInputStream((fileName), DEFAULT_CHARSET_NAME);
            final InputStream seqStream = new SequenceInputStream(fileNameStream, fs.open(file));
            final FSDataInputStream inStream = new InputStreamFSInputWrapper(seqStream);

            return doWithCleanupOnException(

            ...
```

Now the file path is included as an extra line in the InputStream. However, I have no idea how this solution influences Flink's CheckPointing feature. I also tried to add the file path length to the fileLength, but than the SplitFetcher throws an exception, saying that the file ended before it should. This solution only for testing and debugging.

I also tried to add path information at the user interface "reader.StreamFormat", for my purpose it is "reader.TextLineInputFormat". However, if I put any additional information in the "read" method, the "Reader" does not get the end of the stream:

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String read() throws IOException {
        return "test" + reader.readLine();
    }
```

I understand that this is not working due to @Nullable, but even if I catch readLine() == null and set the output of read() to null the program runs to infinity. Any solution to this would be good, because from my point of view this is the interface the user should use. The solution above is more of a creepy hack.

---

I also found a second solution related to "reader.StreamFormat". The problem was, that I tried to catch the reader.readLine() == null. Of course one have to use if-else statement. The only problem left was getting the path information. So you have to rewrite the signature of method

```
    Reader<T> createReader(
        Configuration config,
        FSDataInputStream stream,
        Path fileName,
        long fileLen,
        long splitEnd)
        throws IOException;
```

I am not sure if the restoreReader(...) also needs the Path for checkpointing. The createReader method is used multiple times, so you have to rewrite all the code, which is fortunately an easy task with a modern IDE. For building you have to skip japicmp check in pom.xml. Once this is done you can implement a StreamFormat Reader to meet your needs, e.g.:

```
    public class TextLineInputFormat extends SimpleStreamFormat<String> {

            ...

            @Override
            public Reader createReader(Configuration config, Path fileName, FSDataInputStream stream) {
            ... }

            public static final class Reader implements StreamFormat.Reader<String> {

                    private final Path fileName;
                    private final BufferedReader reader;

                    Reader(final Path fileName, final BufferedReader reader) {
                        this.fileName = fileName;
                        this.reader = reader;
                    }

                    @Nullable
                    @Override
                    public String read() throws IOException {
                        final String lineInFile = reader.readLine();

                        if (lineInFile != null) {
                            return fileName.getPath() + ": " + lineInFile;
                        } else {
                            return null;
                        }
            }
            ...
    }
```

Even if the change of interfaces seems ugly at first sight, this second solution is the better one, as it does not affect the functions of Flink and uses the intended interface.